# What is the meaning of も in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

So this is the sentence in question:

> 義理チョコをもらっても嬉しくないでしょう？

What I don't understand is the exact purpose of the last も in もらって**も**. I have 2 different interpretations:

1. It's there to emphasize 嬉しくない.
2. It's part of a te-form + も structure and express that the action is inconsequential (meaning something like *"(You) won’t be happy **even** if you get (an) obligatory chocolate, right?)"*

So which one is correct? Or is there some other use of the も particle that I am not considering?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning 2 is correct.

In dictionaries, [ても](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82/#jn-152504) has an independent entry. It translates to *even if, although*.

> １ 未成立の事柄を仮定条件として述べ、その条件から考えられる順当な結果と対立する内容の文へ結びつける意を表す。たとえ…したとしても。「失敗し―あきらめはしない」「煮―焼い―食えない」
>
> ２ 既定的な事柄を述べ、その条件から考えられる順当な結果と対立する内容の文へ結びつける意を表す。…たにもかかわらず。「知ってい―知らぬ顔をする」
>
> ３ （多く「にしても」「としても」の形で）ある事柄を仮定条件として認めて、下の文の叙述を起こす意を表す。「自信があるにし―、試験を受けるのはいやな気分だ」